My Dell PowerEdge R720 only boots after a hard reset. iDRAC and power button fail post-shutdown. Won’t turn back on without a full physical reset
I’ve run into a frustrating issue with this used Dell PowerEdge R720 I just bought, and I’m hoping someone here can help me figure this out.
After resetting everything to factory settings and updating all firmware to the latest versions (except 1, more on that later), I’ve noticed that anytime my server shuts down (gracefully or otherwise), it goes into an unresponsive state where:

The server won’t power back on by pressing the power button.
iDRAC shuts off completely

(no IPMI, no web access, no LCD activity.)


only sign of life once it
enters this state state is a few led lights on the motherboard (e.g.,
PCIe slots in the back), but no fans or anything like that (my R630
intermittently turns on the fan for a few seconds when my server is
off, not sure if the lack of fan activity is normal for R720)

The only way to bring it back to life is to do a full hard reset:

Disconnect the PSUs.
Remove the CMOS battery.
Hold the power button to drain residual power.
Replace the CMOS battery, reconnect power, and then the server boots normally (automatically boots without me pressing the power button).


Additional Details:

The power button does work to turn the server off if it’s already running, but it won’t turn it back on.
Once it's up/during operation, everything works fine and iDRAC is accessible and functional.
Restarts (via Ctrl + Alt + Del) work without issue and don't cause the system + iDRAC to turn off.
Diagnostics (ePSA and Lifecycle Controller tests) report no hardware issues.

What I’ve Tried:

Reset to factory defaults:

Cleared all BIOS settings to default and ensured “iDRAC Power On” is enabled.


Firmware Updates:

Updated BIOS, iDRAC, and Lifecycle Controller firmware to the latest versions using Dell’s Server Update Utility.
Only exception is the PSU firmware which requires (based on Dell's firmware updater) a graceful shutdown of the system and then to wait 3-10 mins to allow the firmware to be installed.

That would be disastrous for me because all graceful shutdowns lead to the "off" state I experience where iDRAC and everything is off. Which would (based on the firmware) warnings brick the PSU.




CMOS Battery:

Verified the CMOS battery voltage (~3V) is healthy.


Power Supplies:

Both redundant PSUs are healthy (green light status).


Physical Checks:

Inspected the motherboard for visible damage (capacitors, traces, etc.)
— Nothing jumps out at me.




I plan to store this server in my attic as part of my homelab, but the fact that it won’t turn back on without a full physical reset is a huge inconvenience. I need a reliable way to remotely power it back on.
I'm almost at the point of sticking the PSUs on a smart PDU and a Raspberry Pi Zero inside the server as a CMOS battery switch lol.
Has anyone experienced this issue with their PowerEdge servers? Could this be a motherboard fault or something else I’ve overlooked?

A quick google search of R270 won't power on shows a surprisingly large number of results (so it's a seemingly common issue) .... have you not seen anything online that offers a workable solution?

@Craig my googling skills must not be great, could you share your keywords? I can’t seem to find anyone with my problem
